# Union of open sets is open

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

The proof is generally pretty straightforward, but my only difficulty is with a small subtlety. The statement is:

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ a collection of open sets. Prove that $\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} U_i$ is open.

My attempt is:

> If $I = \emptyset$, then $\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} U_i = \emptyset$, which is open, so we proceed under the assumption that $I \neq \emptyset$. Furthermore, if $U_i = \emptyset$ for all $i \in I$, then $\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} U_i = \emptyset$, which is open, so assume $U_i \neq \emptyset$ for at least one $i \in I$. So, let $x \in \bigcup\limits_{i \in I} U_i$. Then $x \in U_{i_0}$ for some $i_0 \in I$. As $U_{i_0}$ is open, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B_{\epsilon} (x) \subset U_{i_0} \subset \bigcup\limits_{i \in I} U_i$, so $x$ an interior point of $\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} U_i$. Therefore, $\bigcup\limits_{i \in I} U_i$ is open.

Every proof of this fact I have every seen completely omits the first two cases I wrote down, where $I = \emptyset$ or $U_i = \emptyset$ for all $i \in I$. Are these even necessary to consider? Are they just too trivial to comment on?

Comment: "be a matrix space" do you mean "metric space"?

Comment: You don't need either of your first two cases. All that is required is showing that every point in the union is an interior point, which the third case shows.

Comment: @MarkSaving Yes, thank you. This was a typo.

Comment: @DonThousand What if there are no such points, though? I understand that this is basically an implication: "If there is such a point, it's interior," but shouldn't I have to at least comment in some way that if the union is empty in other of those two ways, it's vacuously open? I'm just trying to find a way to justify this to myself.

Comment: If you show it for arbitrary open $U_i$, then you've already shown it when $U_i=\varnothing$ because $\varnothing$ is open.

Comment: @Stuck But doesn't the proof rely on picking an $x$ in the union and asserting there exists an $i \in I$ such that $x \in U_i$? If $I = \emptyset$ or $U_i = \emptyset$ for all $i$, that's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is simply no need to comment on these two cases. Doing so is a distraction, complicates the proof, and makes the proof nonconstructive.

You are attempting to prove that $U := \bigcup\limits_{i \in I} U_i$ is open.

The definition of this is: for all $x \in U$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $B_\delta(x) \subseteq U$.

The proof goes:

Suppose that $x \in U$. Then by the definition of $U$, there exists $i \in I$ such that $x \in U_i$. Since $U_i$ is open, take some $\delta > 0$ such that $B_\delta(x) \subseteq U_i$. Since $U_i \subseteq U$, we have $B_\delta(x) \subseteq U$.

This is simply how one proves a universally quantified statement. To prove $\forall x \in a P(x)$, we suppose that $x \in a$ and prove $P(x)$. This is the logical rule for proving a universally quantified statement. It works perfectly well in the case where $a$ happens to be empty.

Comment: Now THAT makes a lot more sense. So if $a$ is empty, that quantification is just vacuously satisfied. If all of the sets are empty, it's likewise vacuously satisfied. It's less a matter of math than of propositional logic.

Comment: @BradG. That's exactly right.